# SCJP Object Orientation Issue

Tags: java, java-6, scjp

I have a problem in understanding Question no.9 from Chapter Object Orientation from the SCJP book by K&B.

**Question:**

```
public class Redwood extends Tree { 

public static void main (String [] args) { 
new Redwood ( ) . go ( ) ; 

} 

void go ( ) { 

go2 (new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ) ) ; 

go2 ( (Redwood) new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ] 

}  

void go2 (Tree tl, Redwood rl) { 

Redwood r2 = (Redwood) tl; 

Tree t2 = (Tree)rl; 
}
}


class Tree { }
```

**Options:**

```
What is the result? (Choose all that apply.) 

A. An exception is thrown at runtime 

B. The code compiles and runs with no output 

C. Compilation fails with an error at line 8 

D. Compilation fails with an error at line 9 

E. Compilation fails with an error at line 12 

F. Compilation fails with an error at line 13
```

The answer given in the book is A because Tree cannot be downcast to Redwood. I am just having problem to understand the concept.

Comment: `go2 ( (Redwood) new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ] ` ? typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Child` class instance can be cast to `Parent` class reference, because since `Child` inherits `Parent` , `Child`  should support all behaviors which `Parent` already supported.

Example

```
class Parent {

   public void getA() {
        return 1;
   }

}

class Child extends Parent {


   public void getB() {
       return 1;
   }

}
```

Now lets consider 2 objects

```
Child c = new Child();
Parent p = new Parent();
```

Now if you do

```
Parent p2 = (Parent) c;
```

this is valid, because when you invoke `p2.getA()`, it will work since `getA()` method is already **inherited** by `c` which is instance of `Child`.

Now if you do

```
Child c2 = (Parent) p;
```

this will not work because, the type of `c2` is `Child`, and the call `c2.getB()` is valid. But since the instance `p` is of type `Parent`, it doesn't have implementation to `getB()` (which was the new method added down in the inheritance by child class).

In simple terms inheritance is an [**IS A**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship

Coming back to your problem

A `Redwood` **IS A** `Tree` so `Tree t = (Tree) (new Redwood());` works. This means a `Redwood` instance can be cast to `Tree`

But a `Tree` **is NOT A** `Reedwood` always (it can be anything).. so `Redwood r = (Redwood) new Tree()` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

>

```
class Tree{
   // super class
}

public class Redwood extends Tree{
   //child class
   public static void main (String [] args) { 
   new Redwood ( ) . go ( ) ; // Calling method go()
    } 

    void go ( ) { 

   go2 (new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ) ) ; 

   go2 ( (Redwood) new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( )); // Problem is Here

   /*
   (Redwood)new Tree(),------>by this line Tree IS-A Redwood Which wrong


   According to Question
     Redwood IS-A Tree So relationship is
     (Tree) new Redwood();


   */

  } 

  void go2 (Tree tl, Redwood rl) { 

  Redwood r2 = (Redwood) tl; 

  Tree t2 = (Tree)rl; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line will throw the exception at runtime :

```
go2 ( (Redwood) new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ));
```

Because you are casting a `Tree` object to `Redwood` which is not possible

Your `Tree` class is the parent class and you cannot down-cast a parent class object to a child class object.

This is not valid :

```
(Redwood) new Tree ( )
```

But the reverse is true.

That is this is perfectly valid :

```
(Tree) new redwood ( )
```

Answer (score 1):

if you pass a tree object as following then it is legal

```
Tree t1 = new Redwood ();
```

Because Tree can be Redwood or an some tree ... so you can't downcast at run time

Answer (score 0):

Option A : An exception is thrown at runtime

because of `go2 ( (Redwood) new Tree ( ) , new Redwood ( ]` //runtime exception

Becasue you are casting Tree object to Redwood object and its not possible.
Your Tree class is the parent class and you cannot down-cast a parent class object to a child class object.

Answer (score 0):

ClassCastException will be thrown when the code attempts to downcast a Tree to a Redwood.
So the correct answer is: **A**

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't compile due to obvious syntax errors: The `]` in the go method has no matching `[`, and the `'` after the go method has no matching `'` either. Additionally, the code lacks two `}`.